# How can I find the date for which a model predicts a specified value?

Tags: r, regression, prediction, data-fitting

I have data that consists of values on dates, e.g.

```
Date       Value
2024-02-12 7
2024-02-13 8
2024-02-14 9
```

I have fit a model to that data and can now calculate the predicted values for a future date:

```
dat <-  read.table(textConnection("
Date Value
2024-02-12 7
2024-02-13 8
2024-02-14 9
2024-04-20 NA
"), header = TRUE, colClasses = c("Date", "integer"))
model <- glm(Value ~ Date, data = dat)
prediction <- predict(model, dat)
```

In this way I can find the predicted value for one single specific date.

But what if I want to find the date for which specific value is predicted?

My solution has been to caculate the predicted values for a long period of time into the future and then search the predicted values to find the corresponding date. This approach often necessitates long sequences and large datasets and long calculation times.

For example, for the sample data above, it would be difficult for me to eyeball on what exact date the value would be 75. I would therefore calculate all values for the next couple of months and then sift through the predicted values to find the date that goes with the value 75.

Is there a more efficient method to find that date directly, without having to calculate a series of values?

For the above example, the model predicts the value 75 for 2024-02-20. What if I didn't know this and wanted to find the date for which the model predicts the value 75 without calculating all values for the next upcoming months?

---

I have asked a follow-up question here: [How can I find the date for which a model from family = poisson(link = "log") predicts a specified value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78194517/23285912)

Comment: Since you have a simple linear model with one predictor: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/chemCal/versions/0.2.3/topics/inverse.predict Or do it your self by rearranging y = beta1 * x + beta0 for x.

Comment: @Roland Thank you! Is there something similar for `family = poisson(link = "log")`? I guess `inverse.predict()` doesn't work for that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rearrange your model equation to calculate this:

```
# Extract the coefficient of the model you've built
coef <- coef(model)

# Calculate the date for your specific value (in this case 75)
result <- (75 - coef[1]) / coef[2]
```

You may need to convert the numeric answer to a date. e.g.

```
as.Date(result , origin = "1970-01-01")
```

Comment: Thank you! Interestingly that calculation returns "2024-04-19" for 75, while `predict()` calculates 75 for 2024-04-20 and 74 for 2024-04-19. Any idea why that should be so?

Comment: I guess some kind of rounding? I'm not sure how rounding would work for dates

Comment: Okay, thank you. Could you explain how you arrived at the calculation `result <- (75 - coef[1]) / coef[2]` ? My model is different from my example (it's a logarithmic model) and transferring your calculation to it directly doesn't work. What was the original calculation that you rearranged and how did you know that you had to subtract and then divide?

Comment: It's just re-arranging `y = mx + c`   75 is `y`, `coef[1]` is `c` and `coef[2]` is `m`

Comment: For logistic regression the equation to rearrange is: `ln(p/1-p) = mx + c`

Comment: So if you replace 75 with `value` your code to solve it would be like this: `result <- (log(value / (1 - value)) - coef[1]) / coef[2]`

Comment: Or do you not mean logistic regression?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I do mean logistic regression. But `value / (1 - value)` is a negative number, if `value > 1` and `log(of a negative Number) = NaN`.

Comment: Value would never be > 1 if it was a logistic regression model

Comment: I have asked a follow-up question with some of my real data: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78194517/23285912

Comment: I see. Just for your info, your model is a poisson model, not a logistic regression model

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do this for a GLM with log-link:

```
y <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
x <- 1:9

fit <- glm(y ~ x, data = data.frame(x, y), family = poisson())

coef(fit)

#prediction
y <- predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(x = 5), type = "response")
#16.65244 

#inverse prediction
inversePredict_logLink <- function(mod, y) {
  coef <- coef(mod)
  stopifnot(length(coef) == 2L)
  (log(y) - coef[[1]])/coef[[2]]
}

inversePredict_logLink(fit, y)
#5
```

Comment: Thank you. Alas, I cannot get this to work for my data. My values increase exponentionally towards the future. But when I try to calculate the date when my values will reach a value that is higher than the ones I have yet measured, using your solution, I get a date in the past – which makes not sense, as there the values should be lower, not higher. I must be making a mistake somewhere, but I'll have to ask another question, it is deviating to far from the present question. But thank you for your time and help!

Comment: You indicate above that you are doing logistic regression, which uses a logit-link and not a log-link. OTOH, you have also claimed to do poisson regressio with a log-link ... You will need to ask an accurate question. But I really recommend that you sit down and do the maths yourself. They are highschool level.

Comment: I have asked a follow-up question with some of my real data: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78194517/23285912